# Should I demolish this closet myself or leave it for a contractor?

Tags: drywall, basement, demolition

I’m an amateur at this, so I’m asking for some guidance on knocking this closet down. I want to turn the corner into just a normal plain corner without all the wood paneling. I would have a professional come in to do the drywall and finishing touches,  but do you think I should even attempt to take this down myself or let the professional do it?

The reason I’m just just hiring someone immediately is because I’ve got carpet coming to be installed this week and I could at least just take the walls out before they arrive so they can install the carpet, then have the pro come in to finish.

[image: Closet outside]

[image: Closet Inside]

[image: Closet Outside Closer]

[image: Paneling]

Comment: Do you really need the extra space?  I know some people do not like the look of wood, but that closet looks quite nice on the outside.  You probably want the wood from it to finish the walls.  You can remove it, but a professional can save the wood for the walls.

Comment: The only concern would be if any of the closet walls are load bearing. Are they?

Comment: It really feels like you should have thought about this a whole lot earlier. Even if you manage to take it down, you'll then have two unequal box sections abruptly end - so box section & wall will need refinishing to bring them up level. Where is the carpet fitter going to line up to? The wall or where the box ought to be?

Comment: Thanks for the replies… absolutely this should’ve been taken care of before the carpet was ordered I admit, thus my rushing through here. 

However, the carpet installers are piece-mealing the house as material becomes available and to work around their schedule, so I was hoping they’d be able to just leave that section unfinished until drywall can be adjusted. Is that even possible with carpet install or does the whole room need to be done at one time?

Comment: They need to stretch it on carpet gripper, so they'll have to finish it up to some given point. Either you trust to skill, luck & judgement, or you have them run it right to the wall & re-cut it later.

Comment: I would be worried about damaging the ceiling.

Comment: Note that the paneling on the left appears to be offset from the wall...

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, delomishing something is easier that building something so it's a good way to start learning. So have at it.

I'd hold off on the carpeting though. It should be the last item to go in, not the first. You don't know how the paneling on the walls is framed and when it's removed and drywall put in, with some insulation if non is there, there would either be a gap or the carpet would have to be cut back. You'll also have to do the ceiling in the closet so another reason to hold off on the carpeting.

Comment: Thanks for the input… do you think the carpet installers would be able to do the entire room minus that corner/wall while I wait for a contractor to finish the work after I take it out?

Comment: The installers will be able to leave that corner.  However they will not be your friends because your poor planning will make them come back again .  Expect them to charge again.  Sometimes looking for things to be cheep costs more money.  Call them and try to reschedule they will appreciate that much more than coming out twice.

Comment: @Timecook  Then there will be a spliced section of carpeting for the floor of the closet.  They can do the room but you'll have a spliced section in the carpet and the carpet will have to be adjusted for the new walls. Plus the carpet could get damaged during the project.

Comment: OP will probably want to save the panelling to continue on the walls, so it will need careful undoing.  The cupboard itself only needs a sledge, but a reciprocating saw might come in handy.